# Checking if float value is in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I am trying to find out if a value is in numpy array. The array is generated using linspace method and gets float64 type. My value is float type. As the outcome "value in array" check always returns false. What is the most efficient way to find out if float value is in float64 array?

```
import numpy as np

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    if value not in array:
        array = np.insert(array, np.searchsorted(array, value), value)
    return array

array = np.linspace(0,1,21)
print(array)
value = 0.3
print(find_nearest(array, value))
```

Comment: Exact matches with a float are iffy, due to impression.  There is a `isclose` function that checks for matches within a tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, just figured it out. The code below works with isclose as you suggested:

```
import numpy as np

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    if not np.any(np.isclose(array, value)):
        array = np.insert(array, np.searchsorted(array, value), value)
    return array

array = np.linspace(0,1,21)
print(array)

value = 0.3

print(find_nearest(array, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

when you print the value of array

```
for value in array:
    print(value)

#op
0.0
0.05
0.1
0.15000000000000002
0.2
0.25
0.30000000000000004  
0.35000000000000003
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
0.6000000000000001
0.65
0.7000000000000001
0.75
0.8
0.8500000000000001
0.9
0.9500000000000001
1.0
```

now you were trying to check 0.3 with 0.30000000000000004, thatwhy it was returning 
    False  all the time, you either round off your value of array to certain decimal place than it will work